# How to create a dynamic and generic Icon Wrapper for FontAwesome Icons in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, font-awesome

I want to create a React Icon-Component to which I just pass a string with the icon name and then the icon gets rendered.

I followed the instructions here: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons

I added the babel-plugin-macros package and then created a component approach which looks like this (Icon.tsx):

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { IconName } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types';
import { icon } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/import.macro'

type Props = {
    iconName: string;
};

const Icon: React.FC<Props> = ({ iconName }) => {
    let iconNameType: IconName = iconName as IconName;

    return (
        <span>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon({ name: iconNameType })} />
        </span>
    );
};

export default Icon;
```

I think it should be enough to cast the string to the IconName type of FontAwesome.

An example call to this component should be like this (Welcome.tsx):

```
import React from 'react';
import Icon from 'Icon';

const Welcome: React.FC = () => {

  let content = (
    <Icon iconName='Heart' />
  );

  return content
};

export default Welcome;
```

There are no build errors, but when I'm starting my Application in the browser, I just get a blank page with this error in the developer tools console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    js index.js:3
    __require2 chunk-TFWDKVI3.js:18
    js node-modules-paths.js:2
    __require2 chunk-TFWDKVI3.js:18
    js async.js:5
    __require2 chunk-TFWDKVI3.js:18
    js index.js:1
    __require2 chunk-TFWDKVI3.js:18
    js index.js:5
    __require2 chunk-TFWDKVI3.js:18
    node_modules @fortawesome_fontawesome-svg-core_import__macro.js:26182
    __require2 chunk-TFWDKVI3.js:18
    <anonymous> @fortawesome_fontawesome-svg-core_import__macro.js:26404
```

Does anybody know where is the mistake in my approach?

Are there better approaches for a dynamic load of the icons based just on a string with the icon name?

Answer (score 1):

In between I found this solution:

```
import React from 'react';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { IconName } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types';
import { fal } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons';

library.add(fal);

type Props = {
    iconName: string;
};

const Icon: React.FC<Props> = ({ iconName }) => {
    let iconNameType: IconName = (iconName.toLowerCase()) as IconName;

    let content = <FontAwesomeIcon  icon={[ 'fal', iconNameType ]}  />

    return (
        <span>
            {content}
        </span>
    );
};

export default Icon;
```